# Does get block ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, android

Snippet 1:

```
private void startLoadingName() {
    for (ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<TextView, Long> entry : mPendingNameRequest.entrySet()) {
        long callId = (Long)entry.getValue();
        NameHolder nameHolder = mNameCache.get(callId);
        nameHolder.name = QueryUtils.loadNameFromDb(mContext, callId);
        nameHolder.status = NameHolder.LOADED;
        // mNameCache is a ConcurrentHashMap
        mNameCache.put(callId, nameHolder);

        updateContactCachedName(callId, nameHolder);
    }

    GsItemLoader.this.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_SET_NAME);
}
```

This snippet is run on a thread other than the UI thread. Every time it executes, the ListView scroll always slows down, so there must be something in the snippet that blocks the UI thread.

I found that `NameHolder nameHolder = mNameCache.get(callId);` will block `mNameCache` until `mNameCache.put(callId, nameHolder);`. But the docs says 'ConcurrentHashMap' won't block in retrieval operations. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: How do you know that `mNameCache` is getting blocked?

Comment: This snippet consists of nothing but comments. As far as I am concerned it doesn't execute at all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I only feels like it is blocked. And i found that the `get` will acquire lock when the key doesn't found in map. link:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/

Comment: @EJP Sorry, i am too lazy to uncomment the code. It has been removed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***(Updated Java-7-based answer with Java 8 changes)***

AFAIK, it MAY block.

(Please correct me if my understanding in ConcurrentHashMap is wrong).

The whole idea of ConcurrentHashMap is, instead having one big array storing the hash table and everyone is locking the whole table, it is in splitted into partitions (you can see the inner class "Segment" in ConcurrentHashMap's source code).  The case that there is "no contention" is only when you are reading or writing to different partitions.

Look close to the source code Stephen C quoted in the other answer, you can see `lock()` and `unlock()` in `readValueUnderLock()`.  If two thread is accessing same partition, it will lock the segment and do its work.

Therefore, if your UI thread is `put`ting to the same key (or other key in same segment), it will block until you finish your `get()`

However, it is not blocking in the sense you are talking about in your question.  It only blocks for the period of accessing (get/put etc), and lock is released once the operation is finished.

---

### <Java 8+>

Although original question was raised during time of Java 7, it is worth to note behavioral change after Java 8.

Starting from Java 8+, implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap` changed drastically.

The major change in implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap` was, instead of dividing into segments, we are using first entry of each bucket as the lock for the bucket for any *change* operation

So, there should be no blocking if you are using Java 8+.

Comment: I agree with you. So it only may block when execute `   NameHolder nameHolder = mNameCache.get(callId);', but if ui thread get values from `mCachedName` at the same time, then ui thread will be blocked.

Comment: The block is only going to be for a microsecond or so.  IMO, this blocking is unlikely to slow things down to the degree that a human being would notice it ... unless you have LOTs of worker threads all hammering away at the same map object.

Comment: @StephenC Agree.  Even he is using a most basic synchronized HashMap, the slow down shouldn't be that obvious.  I doubt OP is having some other problem in his program... :P

Comment: the answer is wrong with java 8 ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @HungNM2 You are right: the implementation of ConcurrentHashMap has changed drastically in Java 8.  Please note that the time I put through this answer was time of Java 7 and therefore behavior in Java 7 should be what OP was expecting. Anyway, thanks for raising this and I will update the answer based on change in Java 8

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no.  Unless there is something else you are not telling us, the `get` call won't block for longer than a microsecond or so.

The source code for the `get` method and its helper method are below.  As you can see, most of the work is done without any locks whatsoever.  The final fetch of the entry value is done under a lock, but the lock will be released almost instantly ... in a `finally` block.

It is safe to say that the `get()` call is not the cause of your problem.

---

```
    /**
     * Reads value field of an entry under lock. Called if value
     * field ever appears to be null. This is possible only if a
     * compiler happens to reorder a HashEntry initialization with
     * its table assignment, which is legal under memory model
     * but is not known to ever occur.
     */
    V readValueUnderLock(HashEntry<K,V> e) {
        lock();
        try {
            return e.value;
        } finally {
            unlock();
        }
    }

    /* Specialized implementations of map methods */

    V get(Object key, int hash) {
        if (count != 0) { // read-volatile
            HashEntry<K,V> e = getFirst(hash);
            while (e != null) {
                if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
                    V v = e.value;
                    if (v != null)
                        return v;
                    return readValueUnderLock(e); // recheck
                }
                e = e.next;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java.htm

(If the link breaks, Google "ConcurrentHashMap android source".)

Comment: Thanks. But the 'mNameCache' is visited in ui thread. So if the work thread make it blocked, So it will stop the ui thread from get the value?

Comment: How is the worker thread going to make it block?  I've shown you that it can't happen in the `get` call, so you just need to check the other calls that the worker makes on the map object.

Answer (score 0):

I checked code java ConcurrentHashMap JDK 17. get() doesn't lock Bucket. it means that you can read Bucket during The bucket is writing (put or remove).

But bucket is locked during write. It means that only one thread can write to change bucket at the same time.

**So, there are three case when read/write concurrently:**

**case 1:** read before write. so read access old bucket

**case 2**: read after write include 2 cases:

```
   case 2.1: read access old bucket if write has not finished changing during read access

   case 2.2: read access new bucket if write has finished changing during read access
```

notice that read is more faster than write. so **case 2.1** can happen